# Installing DB2 9.7.4 Express-C on Ubuntu 11.04 64 bit

Tags: linux, ubuntu, db2

Im trying to install DB2 9.7.4 Express-C on Ubuntu 64 bit.

Ive done it before on 32 bit Ubuntu with no problem, however on the 64 bit architecture the installation hangs / freezes.

As per this webpage [DB2 Installation Requirements](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r5/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.luw.qb.server.doc/doc/r0008865.html) I installed the libaio package using (sudo apt-get install libaio), however the compat-libstdc++ is not available on synaptic package manager. I found an RPM on the [RPM SEEK](http://www.rpmseek.com) website, however Im not sure if this is what I should be installing and if so which RPM I should use ?

Has anyone had this problem before, and if so provide some guidance (providing some links / commands would be useful)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you read [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/wikis/display/im/DB2+and+DB2+Connect+9.7+for+Linux+-+Supported+Environments) it does not list Ubuntu 11.04 as a supported distribution of Linux. It oddly lists 10.04 LTS but that is also not going to work. You would need to go back to 8.04 LTS because that is the Ubuntu version that has the shared library you need. In this case, libstdc++.so.5.

I can not stress enough how much I would recommend using Red Hat or CentOS instead of Ubuntu for running DB2. If you are going to run enterprise grade software you should use enterprise grade operating systems. Even Debian would be a better choice.

You *can* install an RPM on Ubuntu and make it work. I just would not recommend it.

Comment: I think Canonical would be offended at not being considered an Enterprise grade OS vendor, especially when other candidates for the title include CentOS.